# NT Authority\System account - SYSTEM group relationship

Tags: windows, permissions, system, service-accounts

There is a system account "NT Authority\System", or "Local System".

And, usually, files or folders has full control security permissions for "SYSTEM", which seems to be a group.

Is there any relationship between these two entities?

I have found no information in internet relating each other.